# Why is job's EmailName empty after being retrieved via SQL when it certainly has a value?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Below query is not capturing EmailName. Any idea whats wrong here?

```
select  
c.AccountID, c.OYBAccountID, c.JobID, c.ListID, c.BatchID, c.SubscriberID, c.SubscriberKey, c.EventDate, c.Domain, 
c.URL, c.LinkName, c.LinkContent, c.IsUnique, c.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, c.TriggeredSendCustomerKey, 
j.EmailName
from
ent._click c
left join ent._job j on c.jobid = j.jobid
```

Comment: What’s the fieldname in your target DE?

Comment: Also, try querying in BU (removing ent. prefix)

Comment: in DE the field name is EmailName

Comment: I tried with removing ent prefix as well, still same issue. I also tried with using as j.emailname as EmailName. As i have EmailName field in target DE.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Suman, removing ENT prefix from _job and renaming email name field to something different worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are inside a child BU, since you are using ENT. prefix.

The problem could be that _job data view has the context of the current BU, as opposed to most other data views, including _click, which are global in scope, and reside in ENT.

So:
Jobs from inside your current BU cannot be found in ENT._Job but simply _Job.

Suggested change marked in the code below:

```
SELECT  
c.AccountID, c.OYBAccountID, c.JobID, c.ListID, c.BatchID, c.SubscriberID, c.SubscriberKey, c.EventDate, c.Domain, 
c.URL, c.LinkName, c.LinkContent, c.IsUnique, c.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, c.TriggeredSendCustomerKey, 
j.EmailName
FROM
ent._click c
LEFT JOIN _job j /* removed ENT. prefix */
on c.jobid = j.jobid
```

Maybe this helps?